# Потокобезопасность HashMap в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Встречал много статей, где предлагают как вполне возможный вариант использовать java.util.HashMap из разных потоков, при этом применив синхронизацию через synchronized или обернув через Collections.synchronizedMap(...).

Данная разновидность Map не имеет volative полей, следовательно, я не понимаю, в чем смысл использовать это из разных потоков через synchronized, если потоки не узнают о изменении Map, т.к. ее поля не volatile.

Пожалуйста, помогите прояснить момент!

Comment: вам надо бы почитать что-нибудь про многопоточность в ```java```, будет полезно.
Касательно вашего вопроса. Гарантируется, что при использовании ```synchronized``` изменения будут видны во всех потоках. А ```volatile``` удобен тем, что не надо любой доступ к переменной синхронизировать; это не значит, что без ```volatile``` всё сломается

Comment: Спасибо большое вам! Я действительно упустил эту тему.

Answer (score 2):

Тема не простая, хотя казалось бы, давайте разберемся как это работает:

При указании `volatile` мы говорим что нужно записать значение сразу в кучу минуя локальный кэш потока. При этом заставляя JVM отказаться от оптимизации.

Вот пример как `volatile` может влиять на поведение потока (допустим у нас есть переменная `int count`):

1. Я поток №1, выполняюсь тут себе.
2. О, мне пришла задача изменить значение `count` на 9, сейчас сделаем.
3. Так, `volatile` нет, меняем значение в локальном кэше, поменяли.
4. Меняем значение в куче, стоп, поток №2 требует времени, ок я подожду.
5. Я вернулся, продолжаем, меняю значение в куче на 9.

Если бы у нас было `volatile int count`, то поток №1 успел бы записать значение за одну операцию сразу в кучу. И тогда поток №2 прочитал бы уже измененное значение потоком №1.

Нужно отметить что, мы не выбираем когда и какой поток будет выполняться. Если JVM считает нужным отдать приоритет на выполнение другому потоку, она это сделает. Может конечно и получиться так что без `volatile` поток № 1 успеет записать значение, а может и нет. Для избежания неоднозначности можно использовать `volatile`.

Это все справедливо для примитивов. Для объектов `volatile` записывает сразу в кучу только ссылку. Допустим есть класс `User` и мы с ним работаем, получается что теперь и поля в `User` нужно пометить `volatile`, тогда рекурсивно и все поля объекты `User` должны быть `volatile`. Теряем всю оптимизацию...

Что же делать? Тут на помощь приходит `synchronized`.
`synchronized` блок дает доступ только одному потоку, второй поток блокируется и ждет выхода первого.

Чем `HashMap` отличается от `synchronizedMap`?

```
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            return provider.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            return provider.get(key);
        }
    }
```

В методы `get()` и `put()` добавлены блоки `synchronized`, как можно заметить синхронизация на одном объекте. Это значит что пока первый поток не выйдет из метода `get()`/`put()`, второй поток будет заблокирован и ждать своей очереди. Как только первый поток выйдет из метода `get()`/`put()`, тогда второй поток разблокируется и сможет войти в метод `get()`/`put()`.

Какой вывод? Первый поток выполняет нужные ему действия получает или вставляет значение, затем приходит второй поток и выполняет свои действия с уже измененными данными (разумеется если выполнялся метод `put()`).

У `synchronizedMap` есть проблема, он блокирует доступ сразу и на чтение и на вставку одновременно, что снижает скорость.

Поэтому есть класс `ConcurrentHashMap`. У него чтение без блокировки, а вот вставлять можно только по очереди, что делает его быстрее `synchronizedMap`.

Какой вывод из этого всего:
Зачем писать самому, если можно использовать уже готовые оптимизированные решения синхронизированных коллекций.

надеюсь я понятно объяснил)

Comment: `тогда рекурсивно и все поля объекты User должны быть volatile` - это не так. Начиная з java 5 запись в `volatile` переменную записывает в основную память все изменения, которые сделал этот поток до записи в `volatile` переменную.

Comment: `класс ConcurrentHashMap. У него чтение без блокировки, а вот вставлять можно только по очереди`. Неправда. Внутреннее хранилище разбито на сегменты (по умолчанию 16). При записи блокируется только тот сегмент, в который попадает элемент, так что может быть до 16 параллельных операций (зависит от того, как вставляемые элементы распределятся по сегментам)

Comment: @RomanKonoval `volatile` у объектов обновляет в памяти только ссылку

Comment: @RomanKonoval https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put-K-V- Почитайте, в документации написано что чтение не блокируется

Comment: @RomanKonoval или это про 16 блоков? Я уже не стал писать подробнее и так много текста. Факт в том что запись по одному и тому же ключу будет синхронизирована